# Plotly: How to customize colors in a donut chart?

Tags: r, colors, plotly, donut-chart

I would like to ask you if you could help me in customizing of colors in a donut chart created by plotly.

The problem is following - I have to recreate a dashboard (from an excel file to a html file). A part of the dashboard is a chart providing us with information about early production of each entity. The chart is a donut chart type by plotly. As each entity is defined by a specific color (defined in RGB) throughout whole dashboard, I need to keep these colors in the donut chart as well. But there is a problem. I always get the following warning:

> Warning message:
>   In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(N, "Set2") :
>     n too large, allowed maximum for palette Set2 is 8
>   Returning the palette you asked for with that many colors

and the resulting donut chart containts only one Entity with a not-specified color (see attached picture below the code). Also, the colors in legend are not those which are defined.

Any idea what to do with it? Thank you so much in advance.

```
# create dataset

dt <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 13, nrow = 19))
colnames(dt) <- c("Entity", month.abb)

for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  dt[i, 1] <- paste("Entity", i, sep="")
  dt[i, -1] <- floor(runif(12, min=0, max=100))
}

# assign colors to entities

dt$"EntityColor" <- c("#074263", "#0B5394", "#3D85C6", "#6D9EEB", "#A4C2F4", "#CFE2F3", "#5B0F00", "#85200C", "#A61C00", "#CC4125", "#DD7E6B", "#E6B8AF", "#F8CBAD", "#F4CCCC", "#274E13", "#38761D", "#E06666", "#CC0000", "#20124D")

dt

     Entity Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec EntityColor
1   Entity1  60  98  88  66   5   4  10  28  96  12  49  36     #074263
2   Entity2  14   0  54  67  55  95  11  67  82  87  54  83     #0B5394
3   Entity3  71  88  61  57  34  84  75  55  67  99  37  95     #3D85C6
4   Entity4  20  29  14  12  31  33  42  88  47  42  73  74     #6D9EEB
5   Entity5  70  77  60  85  59  69  28  14  53  91   2  86     #A4C2F4
6   Entity6  50  12  72  18  38   2  23  98  61  39  70  36     #CFE2F3
7   Entity7   1  69  86  16  73  61  72  43  85  35  87  86     #5B0F00
8   Entity8  64  58  73  80  38  60  18  66  25  29  89  96     #85200C
9   Entity9  36  49  20  15  54  89  62  94  68  38  60   4     #A61C00
10 Entity10  98  11  61  42  58  87   9  20  75  53  13  65     #CC4125
11 Entity11  78  66  34  30  92   2  59  63   9  74  46  29     #DD7E6B
12 Entity12  21  82  14  80  51  66   5  54   4  38   0  20     #E6B8AF
13 Entity13  22  75  68  91   0  77  99  69  46  20  63  63     #F8CBAD
14 Entity14   7  75  31  15  86  65  64   6  20  75  21  45     #F4CCCC
15 Entity15  65  67  42  55  89  11  20  47   2  26  28  62     #274E13
16 Entity16  79  29  68  30  72  98  54  88  47  80  14  67     #38761D
17 Entity17  41  68   7  59  62  70  36  44  44  94   2  63     #E06666
18 Entity18   5   1  25  99  27  49  16  98  40  18  59  24     #CC0000
19 Entity19  11  20  31  62  93  32  67  81  54  12   6  10     #20124D


# create donut chart

dt %>%
  mutate(Sum = rowSums(dt[, -c(1,ncol(dt))])) %>%

  plot_ly(labels = ~Entity, 
          values = ~Sum,
          textposition = "inside",
          textinfo = 'label+percent',
          color = ~Entity,
          marker = list(color = ~EntityColor)) %>%

  add_pie(hole = 0.4) %>%

  layout(showlegend = T,
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = F),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = F),
         annotations = list(text=sum(rowSums(dt[, -c(1,ncol(dt))])), "showarrow"=F, font=list(size = 40)))
```

[image: donut chart here]

Comment: How does the second attempt look to you?

Comment: It looks how it should look! Great job! Could you share the code with me, please?

Comment: Code in place! Hope it works for you!

Comment: @vestland It works! Thank you so much! If I understand it was just about to two addition (adding the type and hole to plot_ly) and one correction (colors instead of color in marker)?

Comment: That's right! And leave out `color = ~Entity`

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. Now I hope you don't mind, but I'd just like to point out that you've recently gathered enough reputation points to earn the right to award posts with your up-votes. I assure you they will be highly appreciated by all who take ther time to answer questions. Or ask them for that matter. The forum even encourages the use of your votes through a couple of badges. Voting on 600 posts (and 25% or more of total votes are on questions) will even earn you a gold [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

Comment: @vestland Okay, I will keep it in mind and I will try to not forget to award useful posts with my up-votes. Also, it would be great to take into consideration a possibility to award those who takes time with answering posts to be able to get some money (cryptocurrency?). It might help motivate people even more. I guess this is especially for the executives.

Comment: @vestland I am sorry to bother you again but I have the same problem with the stacked bar chart. Do you happen to know what should I change in the following code?

Comment: Personally I find the most motivation through the extremely effective learning process through problem-solving and communicating with others. I think that *accepting* an answer is *very* important since it makes it easier to discern which questions to take a look at when I'm browsing for a challenge. And *many* just leave a "thank you" and that's it. And lately, especially after the voting system changed a bit, people seem more reluctant to leave their up-votes. As for myself, I hit that up-button as soon as anyone shows a real effort in their questions or post a useful answer.

Comment: Time to move the conversation to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206450/room-for-vestland-and-haraslub) if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you needed to have `type='pie'` `in plot_ly()`, comment out `color = ~Entity,` and specify `marker = list(colors = ~EntityColor)`.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
dt <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 13, nrow = 19))
colnames(dt) <- c("Entity", month.abb)

for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  dt[i, 1] <- paste("Entity", i, sep="")
  dt[i, -1] <- floor(runif(12, min=0, max=100))
}

# assign colors to entities

dt$"EntityColor" <- c("#074263", "#0B5394", "#3D85C6", "#6D9EEB", "#A4C2F4", "#CFE2F3", "#5B0F00", "#85200C", "#A61C00", "#CC4125", "#DD7E6B", "#E6B8AF", "#F8CBAD", "#F4CCCC", "#274E13", "#38761D", "#E06666", "#CC0000", "#20124D")

dt %>%
  mutate(Sum = rowSums(dt[, -c(1,ncol(dt))])) %>%

  plot_ly(labels = ~Entity, 
          values = ~Sum,
          textposition = "inside",
          textinfo = 'label+percent',
          type='pie',
          hole=0.4,
          #color = ~Entity,
          marker = list(colors = ~EntityColor)
          ) %>% add_pie(hole = 0.4) %>%

  layout(showlegend = T,
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = F),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = F),
         annotations = list(text=sum(rowSums(dt[, -c(1,ncol(dt))])), "showarrow"=F, font=list(size = 40)))
```

I hope this is what you were looking for. Don't hesitate to let me know if not.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your feedback. Unfortunately, that is not what I need. Those colors printed in the graph do not correspond with the colors I defined in the column “EntityColor”.