# Plotly: How to customize colors in a stacked bar chart?

Tags: r, plotly, stacked-chart

I would like to ask you if you could help me in customizing of colors in a **stacked bar chart** created by plotly.

The problem is following - I have to recreate a dashboard (from an excel file to a html file). A part of the dashboard is a chart providing us with information about early production of each entity. The chart is a stacked bar chart type by plotly. As each entity is defined by a specific color (defined in RGB) throughout whole dashboard, I need to keep these colors in the donut chart as well. But there is a problem. I always get the following warning:

> Warning message:
>   In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(N, "Set2") :
>     n too large, allowed maximum for palette Set2 is 8
>   Returning the palette you asked for with that many colors

and the resulting donut chart containts only one Entity with a not-specified color. Also, the colors in the legend are not those which are defined.

Any idea what to do with it? Thank you so much in advance.

**Code:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

dt <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 13, nrow = 19))
colnames(dt) <- c("Entity", month.abb)

for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  dt[i, 1] <- paste("Entity", i, sep="")
  dt[i, -1] <- floor(runif(12, min=0, max=100))
}

# assign colors to entities

dt$"EntityColor" <- c("#074263", "#0B5394", "#3D85C6", "#6D9EEB", "#A4C2F4", "#CFE2F3", "#5B0F00", "#85200C", "#A61C00", "#CC4125", "#DD7E6B", "#E6B8AF", "#F8CBAD", "#F4CCCC", "#274E13", "#38761D", "#E06666", "#CC0000", "#20124D")

data.table::melt(dt) %>%

  plot_ly(x = ~variable,
          y = ~value,
          type = "bar",
          color = ~Entity,
          marker = list(colors = ~EntityColor)
  ) %>%

  layout(yaxis = list(title = ""),
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         barmode = 'stack')
```

**Plot:**

[image]

Comment: How did that last suggestion work out for you?

Comment: @vestland It works smoothly! Thank you very much! Btw it is interesting that the solution for "donut chart" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59857236/plotly-how-to-customize-colors-in-a-donut-chart) does not need this kind of loop. Any idea why?

Comment: I'm still a bit puzzled by that. Go to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206450/room-for-vestland-and-haraslub)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Refined approach after comments:

Since the colors turned out to be a bit tricky (see initial suggestion below) I had to break the whole thing down and use a combination of `plot_ly()` and `add_traces()` in a loop to make sure that the plotly settings did not apply colors in the wrong order.
The following plot should be exactly what you're looking for.

**Plot:**

[image]

Note that I've appended a continuous numerical column `ID`. Why? Because you wanted the names in alphabetical order, and the rows are added to the plot in the order they appear in your source. And It's a bit tricky since a straight up ordering using `dt %>% arrange((Entity))` would give you `Entity1, Enitity10, Entity11` etc. Let me know if you'd like to adjust this in any other way.

**Code:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

# data
set.seed(123)

dt <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 13, nrow = 19))
colnames(dt) <- c("Entity", month.abb)
for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  dt[i, 1] <- paste("Entity", i, sep="")
  dt[i, -1] <- floor(runif(12, min=0, max=100))
}

# assign colors to entities
dt$"EntityColor" <- c("#074263", "#0B5394", "#3D85C6", "#6D9EEB", "#A4C2F4", "#CFE2F3", "#5B0F00", "#85200C", "#A61C00", "#CC4125", "#DD7E6B", "#E6B8AF", "#F8CBAD", "#F4CCCC", "#274E13", "#38761D", "#E06666", "#CC0000", "#20124D")



# sort data
dt$ID <- seq.int(nrow(dt))
dt <- dt %>% arrange(desc(ID))


# specify month as factor variable to ensure correct order
months=names(dt)[2:13]
months<- factor(months, levels = c(months))

# plotly setup
p <- plot_ly(type = 'bar')

# add trace for each entity
nrows = nrow(dt)
for(i in 1:nrows) {
    p <- p %>% add_trace(x=months, y = unlist(dt[i,2:13], use.names=F), type = 'bar',
                         #name = paste(dt[i,1], dt[i,14], sep = "_"),
                         name = dt[i,1],
                         type = 'bar',  
                         marker=list(color = dt[i,14])) %>%
       layout(barmode = 'stack')

}

# Edit layout
p <- p %>% layout(title = list(xanchor='right', text='Correct colors, orderered legend'),
                  yaxis = list(title = ''),
                  xaxis = list(title = 'month'))
p
```

**Color correctness verification:**

[image]

#### Initial suggestion

Here's an initial suggestion. First of all, `color = ~Entity` has got to go. And `marker = list(color = ~EntityColor)` versus `marker = list(colors = ~EntityColor)` gives two different results. What makes matters *even* stranger is that the [pie chart documentation](https://plot.ly/r/pie-charts/) uses:

```
marker = list(colors = colors, ...)
```

... and the [bar chart documentation](https://plot.ly/r/bar-charts/) uses:

```
marker = list(color = c('rgba(204,204,204,1)', 'rgba(222,45,38,0.8)', ...)
```

...without the ***`s`*** at the end of `color`.

Either way, you should test both `marker = list(color = ~EntityColor)` and `marker = list(colors = ~EntityColor)` and see what's correct for you.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
dt <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 13, nrow = 19))
colnames(dt) <- c("Entity", month.abb)

for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  dt[i, 1] <- paste("Entity", i, sep="")
  dt[i, -1] <- floor(runif(12, min=0, max=100))
}

# assign colors to entities

dt$"EntityColor" <- c("#074263", "#0B5394", "#3D85C6", "#6D9EEB", "#A4C2F4", "#CFE2F3", "#5B0F00", "#85200C", "#A61C00", "#CC4125", "#DD7E6B", "#E6B8AF", "#F8CBAD", "#F4CCCC", "#274E13", "#38761D", "#E06666", "#CC0000", "#20124D")

data.table::melt(dt) %>%

  plot_ly(x = ~variable,
          y = ~value,
          name= ~Entity,
          type = "bar",
          #color = ~Entity,
          marker = list(colors = ~EntityColor)
  ) %>%

  layout(yaxis = list(title = ""),
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         barmode = 'stack')
```

Take a look and see how it works out for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks great! Is there any chance to have the entities names in the legend instead of the colors names?

Comment: @haraslub Yes, just include `name= ~Entity`.

Comment: Perfect, I will test it once I am on the computer! Thanks

Comment: I have just gone through the code. Unfortunately, I found out several discrepancies. Firstly, the colors are not those colors defined in the column `~EntityColor` (it should look like exactly like in the previous post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59857236/plotly-how-to-customize-colors-in-a-donut-chart ); So, I deleted **s** from the `marker = list(colors = ~EntityColor)` and it seemed that correct colours were used. (continue with the following comment)

Comment: ... But I found out that the colors of Entities do not correspond with the colors of Entities in the donut chart (see the link above) and I did use the same dataset. Any idea what to do with this? Thank you in advance @vestland, I really appreciate it.

Comment: and one more thing (sorry for that). Do you happen to know how to sort alphabetically names of entities in the legend?

Comment: It seems so. I have checked the colors and it works fine.

Comment: @haraslup, OK I'll take a look at it again